# Django-allauth: Error: No module named uni_form

Tags: django, django-allauth

I am just installed django-alluauth .

There is an example inside the project .When I am trying to run

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

I am getting an error `Error: No module named uni_form`.

I didn't change anything .I dont know why I am getting this error .Please help me out .

Thanks

Comment: Have you followed the instructions? https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/tree/master/example

Comment: I have not created virtual environment

Answer (score 0):

This means you don't have django-uni-form installed:

> pip install django-uni-form

This package is probably a dependency of allauth. The package is used to generate forms, but beware that the package is currently deprecated.

I would recommend using django-crispy-forms instead.

> pip install django-crispy-forms

This would however probably require changing some code in allauth, so it is easier to just install django-uni-form.